# Two null residues that shouldn't while expanding function as series of poles

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I am interested in the following ratio of integrals, and I am working with Wolfram Cloud:
\begin{equation}
R = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\, x^2 e^{-i a x^2+i bx^4}}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\, e^{-i a x^2+i bx^4}}
\end{equation}
The result coming from the code `Integrate[x^2 Exp[-I a x^2+ I b x^4],{x,-Infinity, Infinity},Assumptions->a<0]/Integrate[Exp[-I a x^2+ I b x^4],{x,-Infinity, Infinity},Assumptions->a<0]` is given in terms of modified Bessel functions of the first kind. In order to express this function as a sum of poles (this is what I want at the end), I used the residue theorem on a prototypical function given by M/P, where M and P are given in:

```
Clear[M,P,n,z0]
M[x_] :=  I/(2x)BesselI[1/4,-I x]+BesselI[3/4,-I x]+BesselI[5/4,-I x]
P[x_] := BesselI[-1/4,-I x]+BesselI[1/4,-I x]
Poles = Solve[BesselI[-1/4,-I z]+BesselI[1/4,-I z]==0 && 0<Re[z]<30 &&-1<Im[z]<0];
z0 = z/.Poles;
Table[N[Residue[M[z]/P[z],{z,z0[[n]]}]],{n,1,7}]
```

This gives the 7 first poles in the region over which I searched them. My problem comes from the third and fourth residues because they are identically 0. But this seems unlikely because the associated poles exist. I searched for a larger strip on the right side of the complex plane, and there is no other pole for which I get 0.

What is happening? I plotted in 3D the absolute value of M[x+Iy]/P[x+Iy] and there is indeed the third and fourth poles, so I don't know what to think about all this...

Comment: The poles are calculated only approximately, this may imply zero rezidues at some poles.

Comment: `ComplexPlot3D[(I/(2 z) BesselI[1/4, -I z] + BesselI[3/4, -I z] + 
    BesselI[5/4, -I z])/(BesselI[-1/4, -I z] + 
    BesselI[1/4, -I z]), {z, 0 - I, 30 + 0*I}, PlotRange -> {0, 100},PlotPoints->50]` indicates five possible poles.

Comment: @user64494 Thank you for your comment! How can there be only five possible poles, when there are seven when I plot the absolute value of the function? Also, its real part, while obviously not containing poles, indicates some precisely in the region where the residue was 0...

Comment: If I express everything in terms of `BesselJ[]` (which is a little nicer to deal with), and look at `ComplexPlot[Sqrt[z] BesselJ[-1/4, z] + Sqrt[-I z] BesselJ[1/4, z], {z, -I, 30}, AspectRatio -> 1/5, ColorFunction -> {Automatic, None}]`, I immediately see nine roots, thus confirming the result of `poles = z /. Solve[Sqrt[z] BesselJ[-(1/4), z] + Sqrt[-I z] BesselJ[1/4, z] == 0 && 0 < Re[z] < 30 && -1 < Im[z] < 0]`.

Comment: Then, if I do `ResourceFunction["NResidue"][(I (Sqrt[-I z] BesselJ[-(3/4), z] - Sqrt[z] BesselJ[3/4, z]))/(Sqrt[z] BesselJ[-(1/4), z] + Sqrt[-I z] BesselJ[1/4, z]), {z, #}] & /@ poles`, it looks as if all the residues are equal to `I`.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you very much! I thought the residues were all $i$, and I was surprised that two of them would be 0, but the code you wrote is perfect for me.

Comment: The command of Maple `RootFinding:-Analytic(BesselI(-1/4, -I*z)+BesselI(1/4, -I*z), z = 0-I .. 30+0*I)` results in 9 zeroes .